# Wp-theme Development

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, permalinks, blog

```
<?php

        query_posts( array(
        'category_name'  => 'notice',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
        ) );

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
           echo '<h1>','<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">';
            the_permalink();     
            the_title();
           echo '</a>','</h1>';

            echo '<p>';
             the_content();
           echo '</p>';    
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_query();

    ?>
```

When I click this heading, My post not showing on single.php
what is the problem?
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: try using `get_permalink` instead of `the_permalink` in the echo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check how the [Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) works, followed by the correct way to instantiate a new [Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Try this:

```
<?php
        // The correct way to create a new Query
        $newquery = new WP_Query( array(
        'category_name'  => 'notice',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
        ));

        // Check if query found posts, then start the Loop
        if($newquery->have_posts) : while ($newquery->have_posts() ) : the_post();
           echo '<h1><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h1>';

             the_content();

        // End post iteration
        endwhile;

        // If query didnt find any posts
        else:

       echo 'No posts in the query';

        // End the Loop and reset the query
        endif; wp_reset_query();
?>
```

If nothing shows up, you should debug the query with:

```
var_dump($newquery);
```

Comment: Please explain the code as how it helps the OP.

Comment: @bravokeyl is it better now?

Comment: I am just use echo '<h1><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h1>'; 
and my problem  solve. Thanks... :D